# Why does vim delay for a second whenever I use the 'O' command (open a new line above and insert)?

Tags: bash, vim, gnome-terminal

When I use most commands, they take effect instantly. When I use the `O` command, however, I see the "O" replace the current character for a about a second, then the current character returns, and a new line is inserted and opened.

I have no such problem with the `o` command (open a new line **below** and insert).

If it makes a difference, I'm using `vim` from `bash`, in the Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the previous key pressed was ESC, this is because there are keys that can generate escape sequences beginning with ESC O.  For example depending on the cursor key mode, the up arrow key may generate the escape sequence ESC O A.

If it sees a partial escape sequence, vim will wait for a short timeout to see if another character is received that matches one of the escape sequences defined for your terminal type.  If not it will treat the characters as separate keystrokes.  You can test this by entering a capital A while waiting for the line to open to see if it treats it as an up arrow instead.

There are some vim settings that can be used to control this.  `:set ttimeoutlen=100` will change the escape sequence timeout to 100ms.  `:set noesckeys` will completely disable recognition of keys sending an escape sequence when in insert mode.  Also, vi-compatible mode will not have this issue because esckeys is off in that mode – that is why `vim -u NONE` works.

Comment: Just to clarify, my "experiment" with the 140k line file was in full vim mode with my standard complement of of plug-ins and filetypes. I can see where you might have concluded that I'd used `-u NONE` but we still lack confirmation from the OP.

Comment: wow! that was mildly irritating for a while but I've never thought about it. makes perfect sense now. Esc O A indeed works just like up-arrow.

Comment: `:set noesckeys` probably isn't what you want - set it and then press the arrow keys in insert mode, even if you don't plan on using them, you don't want them to do that! noesckeys also doesn't speed things up outside of insert mode.  `ttimeoutlen` is definitely the way to go